# input[type=text] displayed value different from obj.value

Tags: javascript, dom

I want an input type=text to function as an input type=date.

The specification is as follows:

- The displayed date should be according to the current locale (lang attribute)
- Getting the value should be in ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD)
- Setting the DOM value should be in ISO 8601
- The POST value should be ISO 8601

Suppose I have this field, with the nl-NL locale:

```
<input lang="nl-NL" value="2012-11-07">
```

I want the field to display 7-11-2012. It's not about the formatting itself, but it's about the getters and setters. You can override getters and setters:

```
Object.defineProperty(inputObject, "value", {
    get : function(){ 
    },
    set : function(newValue){ 
    }
});
```

-

```
<input id="date" lang="nl-NL" value="2012-11-07">
```

should be *displayed* as **7-11-2012**

```
document.getElementById('date').value
```

should return **2012-11-07**

```
document.getElementById('date').value = '2012-11-07'
```

should again be *displayed* as  **7-11-2012**

Comment: getter and setter are deprecated and should not be used - you'd be better served by writing your own custom methods since you wont be able to change how the DOM works...

Comment: writing custom methods won't be possible as this will have to work as a standard library.

Comment: Are you sure your design is what you want? It is confusing if `element.value` doesn't actually work regularly. If you don't want custom methods to the elements, what about wrapping? Something like a `$` function that returns an object with a getter like `$(element).value`.

Comment: If a browser supports a native <input type="date">, the above behavior is shown. To make sure this works in other browsers that don't support date, I want to make a Javascript library that makes it work the same. (together with a datepicker and other UI elements).

That's why I want to override the default obj.value getter and setter.

Comment: I see you changed to Object.defineProperty - but that wont work in all browsers (e.g. IE<9). Any specific browser you are trying to support? Here's some other ideas on providing a date picker for backward compatibility (using jQuery-UI): http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-cross-browser-datepickers-within-minutes/ or even with dynamic loading: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/createelementcheck2.shtml

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.

Ideally I would like to support the same browsers Twitter Bootstrap does (https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/wiki/Browser-Compatibility).

What I'm trying to accomplish is to make a cross-browser library that provides date functionality exactly the same as a browser would natively do. So the display should be according to the locale (as the spec says) and the value should be like an ISO 8601 date.

I know how to bind a datepicker to an <input> field. I know how to not override native browser behaviour.